# typedef stuct problem in C (illegal use of this type as an expression)

Tags: c, struct, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [typedef stuct problem in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385533/typedef-stuct-problem-in-c)

Hello there

I am facing I have defined I a structure in a C header file:

```
typedef struct iRecActive{

    char iRecSID[32];
    unsigned char RecStatus;
    int curSel;

}iRecAcitve_t;
```

but when I use the same structure in another file, the compiler gives some error:

error C2275: 'iRecActive_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression
        d:\project\project original\mirec2pc v1.0\httpapp\httpapplication.h(15) : see declaration of 'iRecActive_t'

I would be obliged if anyone could help me out

Regards

Umair

Comment: Post the code that causes the error.

Comment: You _still_ have `iRecAcitve_t` misspelt despite the fact that you've accepted that answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385533/typedef-stuct-problem-in-c

Comment: I am sorry I have changes the spelling but I forgot to change is here. After changing the spelling I am getting this problem

Comment: Apologies then, @Umair, I've voted to reopen this one but it might be better to create _another_ question, spell it right, and (this is important) state that it's a new problem so people here (me in particular) don't go off half-cocked and vote to close again :-)

Comment: can you post the piece of code where you used the typedef tag to create instance of iRecAcitve_t ?

Comment: well you still have your spelling mistakes here too .... iRecAcitve_t, iRecActive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could check you spelling, both in the question and in the code. You seem to have declared it as iRecAcitve_t but use iRecActive_t

Comment: well. I am sorry that I haven't corrected the spelling in the question but I have already changed it in my code. But after changing the spelling the compiler recognizes iRecActive_t; as a structure but give that particular error. I am still clueless why is the compiler doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you've used the typename where the compiler expects...something else.

For example:

```
iRecActive_t *thing = iRecActive_t; // compiler expects new iRecActive_t()

if (iRecActive_t) {} // compiler expects an expression
```

As others have said, you need to post the line it's complaining about (line 15 of `httpapplication.h`)

**Edit**

`iRecActive_t iRecActiveObj[4];` appears to be legal, in which case it's probably *the line before* that's got the compiler confused. For example:

```
if (thingOne ==                     // oops
    iRecActive_t iRecActiveObj[4];
```

Comment: iRecActive_t iRecActiveObj[4];

this is the line for which compiler is showing the respective error